# How to allow overlap between grid cells?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

In Grid, is there a way to allow my text to overlap into the cell next to it?

The time (as seen in the image) auto updates. As the time increases to minutes the whole grid increases in width, which I don't want. I just want the text to overlap into the next cell instead of widening the column.

Thanks

```
.feed {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  background-color: #1C232E;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  }
```

[Image of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNpxP.png)
[Image of unwanted behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePL8o.png)

Comment: Just upload here, do not link to another site..

Comment: It didn't allow me to directly upload here, it said I needed more reputation.

Comment: Can you make this a 1x2 grid so that the top row spans the entire width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't adjust grid column spans dynamically, without Javascript. You can just put both text items in the same cell, and position them how you want, with flexbox for example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  color: #fff;
  grid-gap: 6px;
}

.grid>div {
  padding: 1em 1em;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.grid > div span:nth-child(2){
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <span>Last updated 1 minute and 49 seconds ago</span>
    <span>watch_server</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Last updated 1 minute and 49 seconds ago</span>
    <span>watch_server</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 1x2 grid, allowing the time to span the container's width:

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #363f55;
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 16px Sans-Serif;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

h4 {
  color: #fff;
}

#app {
  width: 50rem;
}

.container {
  background-color: #1c2028;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "timestamp timestamp" ".    server";
  padding: 2rem;
}

.container .timestamp {
  color: grey;
  grid-area: timestamp;
}

.container .server {
  color: #698081;
  grid-area: server;
}
```

```html
<section id="app">
  <div class="sample">
    <h4>Shortish Date</h4>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="timestamp">
        Last Update: 14 Seconds Ago
      </div>
      <div class="server">
        <p class="name">watch_server</p>
        <p class="id">1578811744288</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sample">
    <h4>Longish Date</h4>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="timestamp">
        Last Update: 1 Minute 49 Seconds Ago
      </div>
      <div class="server">
        <p class="server-name">watch_server</p>
        <p class="server-id">1578811744288</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would also reevaluate the colors. The text is almost completely illegible.